# Silverlight Supported Codecs

Tags: .net, silverlight, mediaelement, codec

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189080%28v=vs.95%29.aspx#delivery_method_containers_and_codecs) is a list of codecs that are supported by Silverlight MediaElement control.

**Question:** Do I need to install these codecs on the client machine Or They are natively supported by Silverlight?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight is self-contained and native support for all those formats is within Silverlight itself.

You do not need to install additional Codecs.

You will have noted that not all Codecs are support on all platforms (WP7 has new ones etc), but that is down to the plugin.

Comment: That's the answer:) So, Is it possible to use some other codecs that are separately installed on the machine in Silverlight?

Comment: In browser, no. In theory OOB mode, via COM, you can connect to anything, but that is more work than generating a Silverlight format for the videos.